# Getting NaN value while querying in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, nan

I fired the below query in Hive:-

```
SELECT gender_hh_mem1, (sum(if(CLICK_FLG='Y' and OPEN_FLG='Y', 1, 0))/
 sum(if(OPEN_FLG='Y', 1, 0))*100) as CTOR FROM campaigndata 
WHERE gender_hh_mem1 is not null 
GROUP BY gender_hh_mem1;
```

I get the below result:-

```
F       11.827956989247312<br>
M       15.18987341772152<br>
U       18.181818181818183<br>
gender_hh_mem1  <b>NaN</b>
```

Why am I getting a `NaN` here? Any clue?

Comment: Could the denominator in your select expression be zero at some point? What's the result of `SELECT DISTINCT gender_hh_mem1 FROM campaigndata`?

Comment: Got it...thanks :)

Comment: The is the result for distinct:-
NULL
F
M
U
gender_hh_mem1

Comment: Could you change the `WHERE gender_hh_mem1 is not null` for this one: `WHERE gender_hh_mem1 IN ("F","M","U")` and check what happens? I'm not sure if this would be the right syntax, but the idea is to select only rows where gender_hh_mem1 is "F", "M" or "U"